# How to add jstl to a Liferay portlet?

Tags: jstl, liferay

I have been looking here in SO and other places and I have not found the exact answer to this question. So here goes:

What is the best way to add support in my Liferay portlets to use JSTL tags?

Of course, I have found generic answers about how to add a taglib to a web app, but not specifically for Liferay.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to add `jstl-api.jar` and `jstl-impl.jar` to your portlet dependencies.

These jar files are already in Liferay `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib`.

So just add this to the file **liferay-plugin-package.properties**:

```
portal-dependency-jars=jstl-api.jar,jstl-impl.jar
```